# How to calculate total amount in every row in DataGridView using SQL Database

Tags: sql, vb.net

Sample Project Output

[image: Project]

I am using vb.net and SQL database

Can someone teach me how to use button to calculate the total amount of the Row in the Datagridview.
I have no idea how can I do it.

e.g

```
    ProductCost              ProductQuantity               TotalAmount

       32                        20                          640

       32                        32                          1024
```

Label3 = TotalAmount

should be like this

```
    ProductCost              ProductQuantity               TotalAmount

       32                        20                          640

       32                        32                          1024
```

Label3 = 640
Label3 = 1024

And I can continually add new items and it will automatically calculate.

Comment: A good start would be to put some thought into where the actual problem is. Either you're using SQL to sum data in the database or you're using VB to sum the data in the application. It can't be both. If you have a `DataTable` contain data then where it came form is irrelevant. That you're displaying it in a grid is irrelevant to, as it happens. The `DataTable` has a `Compute` method. You should use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellLeave
        Try
            For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                DataGridView1.Item("TotalAmount", i).Value = DataGridView1.Item("ProductCost", i).Value * DataGridView1.Item("ProductQuantity", i).Value
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```